# ASP.NET ListView DataSource is string[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview

Usually I would do this to display the data:

`<%# Eval("string") %>` This would work if the datasource was not an array of type string.
Since there is no expression for the Eval method. How should I display the data?

aspx

```
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

codebehind:

```
    string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(UploadsPath);
    lvSlideShow.DataSource = images;
    lvSlideShow.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `Container.DataItem`. It is pointing at the current thing in the `IEnumerable` object being bound to.:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Container.DataItem %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you cannot use Eval() for string[]. 
You can use `GridView` as it has `AutoGenerateColumns` functionality.